# Custom changes stopped showing on Admin Order View

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a custom pdf generator for labels and I had it calling a function on the admin order view page. 
The files I edited are: /public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml

This worked great so far, with the links before the "Edit" on the shipping adress. But somehow, the links have gone away and I can't figure out why as the info.phtml wasn't changed.

Before:

```
<div class="box-right">
    <!--Shipping Address-->
    <div class="entry-edit">
        <div class="entry-edit-head">
            <h4 class="icon-head head-shipping-address"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Address') ?></h4>
            <div class="tools"><?php echo $this->getAddressEditLink($_order->getShippingAddress())?></div>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <address><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated(true) ?></address>
        </fieldset>
    </div> </div>
```

After my changes (it has been working until now... ) :

```
<div class="box-right">
    <!--Shipping Address-->
    <div class="entry-edit">
        <div class="entry-edit-head">
            <h4 class="icon-head head-shipping-address"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Address') ?></h4>            <span style="float:right;margin-left: 0.5em;"><a href='#' style="color:#FFCC22"  onclick="labelPrintLandscape()">Etiqueta</a></span>            <span style="float:right;margin-left: 0.5em;"><a href='#' style="color:#FFCC22"  onclick="labelPrintPortrait()">Registo</a></span>          <span style="float:right;margin-left: 0.5em;"><b>Print Label:</b></span>
            <div class="tools"><?php echo $this->getAddressEditLink($_order->getShippingAddress())?></div>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <address><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated(true) ?></address>
        </fieldset>
    </div> </div>
```

Comment: remove your cache and check

Comment: Already tried disabling it and refreshing. But this has been working for more than 1 month and cache has never been a problem :/

Comment: Then Some other problem try to check error log or enable errors in php.ini

Comment: Nothing unusual on systemlog and no exception log.

Comment: Found the problem, searched for info.phtml on Cpanel and found a new file on an extension folder, edited that one and it started working. Hours lost because of a stupidity...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was about a wrong configuration and  went away on it's own (stated in the comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.  It was an extension causing the problem.

It was an affiliate extension (Affiliate Pro), since it had "replaced" the admin order view file (/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml). By "replaced" I mean that it created a new file under the extension directory, where magento was getting the info.phtml information from instead of the regular default file. The tip here is, if you cleared your cache and things aren't showing, go on cpanel and search for the filename that you're changing to check if there is a new file with the same name under an extension folder.

Comment: Please post what extension and why it was causing an issue so future readers have some benefit from this thread

Comment: It was an affiliate extension (Affiliate Pro), since it had "replaced" the admin order view file (/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml).
By "replaced" I mean that it created a new file under the extension directory, where magento was getting the info.phtml information from instead of the regular default file.
The tip here is, if you cleared your cache and things aren't showing, go on cpanel and search for the filename that you're changing to check if there is a new file with the same name under an extension folder.